# Composable in NavGraphBuilder is repeating 3 or more times

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem when do a call to my composable in the `NavGraph`, it is repeating 3 times or sometimes more times. I have looked where I do the call and I don't see any loop or something.

`NavGraph`

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.addScheduleDetails(
    navController: NavHostController,
    userDataViewModel: UserDataViewModel,
    titulos: MutableState<String>,
    datosViewModel: DatosViewModel,
){
    val animationState = mutableStateOf(true)
    composable(route = MainDestinations.SCHEDULE_DETAILS_ROUTE+"/{${NavArguments.NOMBRE_HORARIO}}")
    {backStackEntry ->

            Log.w("Call", "ScheduleDetails")
            titulos.value = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(NavArguments.NOMBRE_HORARIO)!!+" "
            val actions = MainActions(navController = navController)

            DetallesHorarioScreen(
                nombreHorario = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(NavArguments.NOMBRE_HORARIO),
                userDataViewModel = userDataViewModel,
                onNavToAddSubject = actions.navigateToAgregarMateria,
                datosViewModel = datosViewModel,
                animationState = animationState
            )
    }
}
```

Prints from LOG

```
2022-01-06 19:57:01.548 30533-30533/horarios W/Call: ScheduleDetails
2022-01-06 19:57:01.613 30533-30533/horarios W/Call: ScheduleDetails
2022-01-06 19:57:01.987 30533-30533/horarios W/Call: ScheduleDetails
```

Call to `composable(route = MainDestinations.SCHEDULE_DETAILS_ROUTE ...)`

```
Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(80.dp)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clickable { onNavToHorario(nombre) },        //Call to navigator
        border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = primaryColorCustom),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10),
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        elevation = 4.dp
    ) {...}
```

`onNavToHorario()`

```
val actions  = MainActions(navController = navController)
(...)
onNavToHorario = actions.navigateToHorario
```

`MainActions()`

```
class MainActions(navController: NavHostController){
    val navigateToHorario:(String) -> Unit = {nomHorario: String ->
        navController.navigate(route = MainDestinations.SCHEDULE_DETAILS_ROUTE+"/${nomHorario}")
    }
}
```

In other case I had a similar problem and was occasioned for animations but I already delete all animations in `NavGraph` but the problem is still

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigation always crossfades destinations, so each screen will always recompose multiple times. This is expected as per the [Thinking in Compose guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#frequent):

> In some cases, a composable function might run for every frame of a UI animation. If the function performs expensive operations, like reading from device storage, the function can cause UI jank.

You aren't doing anything wrong (you aren't [triggering side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) as part of composition), so your code is already fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer, so I have some variables in the destination and they are be cleaning on each recompose, how I avoid that??

Comment: That's what `remember` is for, as per the [State in composables guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables).