# Prevent Screens Recomposing In Background/Backstack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Simplified this code as much as I can, but I still get multiple recompositions from the screen level composables:

**Activity**

```
class RackInspectionModuleActivity: ComponentActivity() {

    val modifier = Modifier

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {

                val navHostController = rememberNavController()

                Surface (
                    modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant
                ){
                    Log.w(TAG, "ACTIVITY - SETUPNAVGRAPH")
                    SetupNavGraph(
                        navController = navHostController                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**SetupNavGraph**

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController ){

    Log.w(TAG, "SetupNavGraph()")

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = RackInspectionScreen.RackInspectionContentsScreen.route
    ){

        composable(route = RackInspectionScreen.RackInspectionContentsScreen.route){
            RackInspectionContentsScreen(
                navController = navController)
        }

        composable(
            route = RackInspectionScreen.RackInspectionIntroductionScreen.route
        ){
            RackInspectionIntroductionScreen(
                navController = navController)
        }
```

**Screen 1 - Contents**

```
@Composable
fun RackInspectionContentsScreen (
    navController: NavController){

    Log.w(TAG, "CONTENTS SCREEN RECOMPOSED")

    Column(
        modifier= Modifier
            .padding(top = 15.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        verticalArrangement= Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp, Alignment.Top)
    ){
    
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(route = "rack_inspection_introduction_screen"){
                    launchSingleTop = true
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Button Clicked")
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Navigate to Introduction Screen")
        }
    }
}
```

**Screen 2 - Introduction**

```
@Composable
fun RackInspectionIntroductionScreen (
navController: NavController){

    Log.w(TAG, "INTRODUCTION SCREEN RECOMPOSED")

    Column(
        modifier= Modifier
            .padding(top = 15.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        verticalArrangement= Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp, Alignment.Top)
    ) {

        Button(onClick = {
            Log.d(TAG, "Button Clicked")
            navController.popBackStack() 
        }) {
            Text(text = "PopBackStack")
        }

    }
}
```

So when I first open the activity, I get the following, which looks fine:

[image]

But when I navigate from screen 1 to screen 2, I get the following recompositions:

[image]

And when I click on the button in Screen 2 (to popBackStack), I get the following recompositions:

[image]

So I understand that the screens will be recomposed multiple times, but I am trying to pass a viewmodel from the activity, through the navigation, to the screen. Then in the screen composable, I draw 'cards' by interating through this filtered data.

So everytime each screen is recomposed, the cards in the screen are recomposed, which seems very inefficient.

I have tried to do this within SideEffect or LaunchedEffect blocks, but as the whole screen gets recomposed, then this still gets applied..

Comment: Dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70615985/1676363) and the expected behavior.

Comment: [answer on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70616013/8644685)

Comment: Hi both, I understand that the screens will be recomposed multiple times, but I am trying to pass a viewmodel from the activity, through the navigation, to the screen. Then in the screen composable, I draw 'cards' by interating through this filtered data.  So everytime each screen is recomposed, the cards in the screen are recomposed, which seems very inefficient.  I have tried to do this within SideEffect or LaunchedEffect blocks, but as the whole screen gets recomposed, then this still gets applied..  How can I avoid this please!?  I'll release the bounty on the best response to this!!

Comment: You are passing the viewmodel from activity to compose is it possible to add a key like already drawn and omit re compose. But this may lead to many issues.